# TensorFlow on Windows: Error when installing with Anaconda 3

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda

Now [TensorFlow is finally released on Windows](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/0.12.0-rc0), I have been trying to install it for the last 2 days, still no success. Need some help please.

After installing Anaconda 3, I followed [the instructions here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/get_started/os_setup.html#anaconda-installation). But was not able to proceed further beyond activating the environment...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just sorted things out...what a journey!! The solution is below:

So basically, we need to follow [the process here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/get_started/os_setup.html#pip-installation-on-windows). Also, you may get an error message like this:

```
Cannot remove entries from nonexistent file c:\users\george.liu\appdata\local\co
ntinuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\easy-install.pth
```

So, you just need to do this instead in Anaconda Prompt:

```
pip install --upgrade --ignore-installed https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

This is due to a known bug as [explained here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/542).

Then you're all set. Enjoy!!

Comment: This worked for me in Windows. I had installed Anaconda earlier.

Comment: The solution was great.Thanks alott*: